# How to migrate SimpleMembership user data to ASPNET Core Identity

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cryptography, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an application that I originally built when I was young and foolish and its authentication is set up using the [SimpleMembership](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates) framework, with all user data contained in a `webpages_Membership` table. I am very interested in rebuilding my backend as an AspNetCore Web API with AspNetCore Identity via SQL Server, without losing user information.

I've had good luck with coming up with SQL scripts to move everything into an `AspNetUsers` table in preparation for working with Identity instead of SimpleMembership, but where I'm running into an issue is password hashing. I gather from articles like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) and [this](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2014/02/migrating-existing-website-from.html) that my best bet is to override `PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>` to duplicate the SimpleMembership crypto flow, and then rehash passwords as they come in to gradually migrate the database.

The trouble is I can't find out how to achieve this flow duplication in .NET Core. The latter article linked above states that the SimpleMembership flow is achieved via the `System.Web.Helpers.Crypto` package, which does not appear to exist in the .NET Core library, and I can't figure out if its implementation is documented anywhere. ([Its MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.111).aspx) says that it is using RFC2898 hashing but I don't know enough about crypto to know if that's enough to go on by itself. This isn't my area of expertise. :( )

Any insight on how to approach this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If there's a reason this was downvoted, I'd like to know so I can improve the question. :/

Comment: Can't you just ask users to reset their password when you migrated to the new system?

Comment: @rawel It's reasonable to assume that rosalindwills would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: any update? I'm having the same troubles

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes Added an answer below. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else who may be running into the same trouble -- I was able to find a copy of the `System.Web.Helpers.Crypto` code somewhere on GitHub, and more or less copied it into a custom password hasher class thus:

```cs
public class CustomPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>
{
    public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(IdentityUser user, string hashedPassword,
        string providedPassword)
    {
        var isValidPasswordWithLegacyHash = VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
        return isValidPasswordWithLegacyHash
            ? PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded
            : base.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hashedPassword, providedPassword);
    }

    private const int _pbkdf2IterCount = 1000;
    private const int _pbkdf2SubkeyLength = 256 / 8;
    private const int _saltSize = 128 / 8;

    public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string password)
    {
        //Checks password using legacy hashing from System.Web.Helpers.Crypto
        var hashedPasswordBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
        if (hashedPasswordBytes.Length != (1 + _saltSize + _pbkdf2SubkeyLength) || hashedPasswordBytes[0] != 0x00)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var salt = new byte[_saltSize];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(hashedPasswordBytes, 1, salt, 0, _saltSize);
        var storedSubkey = new byte[_pbkdf2SubkeyLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(hashedPasswordBytes, 1 + _saltSize, storedSubkey, 0, _pbkdf2SubkeyLength);
        byte[] generatedSubkey;
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, _pbkdf2IterCount))
        {
            generatedSubkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(_pbkdf2SubkeyLength);
        }
        return ByteArraysEqual(storedSubkey, generatedSubkey);
    }

    internal static string BinaryToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        var hex = new char[data.Length * 2];
        for (var iter = 0; iter < data.Length; iter++)
        {
            var hexChar = (byte) (data[iter] >> 4);
            hex[iter * 2] = (char) (hexChar > 9 ? hexChar + 0x37 : hexChar + 0x30);
            hexChar = (byte) (data[iter] & 0xF);
            hex[iter * 2 + 1] = (char) (hexChar > 9 ? hexChar + 0x37 : hexChar + 0x30);
        }
        return new string(hex);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    private static bool ByteArraysEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, b))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (a == null || b == null || a.Length != b.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var areSame = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            areSame &= (a[i] == b[i]);
        }
        return areSame;
    }
}
```

This class overrides `VerifyHashedPassword` and checks whether the user's provided password works with the old Crypto hashing; if so, the method returns `PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded`. Otherwise, it passes the password off to the base class's method and verifies it as normal with the .NET Core hashing behavior.

You can then instruct your `UserManager` to use this password hasher instead of the default by including it in your dependency injection configuration in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public class Startup 
{
...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    ...
        services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>, CustomPasswordHasher>();
    }
...
}
```

My eventual intention is to have my controller trigger a rehash of the user's password when that `SuccessRehashNeeded` result is returned, allowing a gradual migration of all users to the correct hashing schema.

Comment: Hey @rosalindwills, have you successfully implemented it?

Comment: @RaghuMU Yes, I successfully implemented it. :) All the code above works.

Comment: @RaghuMU That depends on how you're implementing your authentication - cookies, tokens, etc. But once you've implemented the code above, you can dependency-inject the `UserManager` or `SignInManager` into your controller and it will use the updated logic for password hashing.